# Checking if an array index is null

Tags: c++, arrays, null

Perhaps someone proficient in C++ can answer this question.
I have an array of values.  I want to know if a specific index in the array exists.  For example:

```
if (array[i] != NULL && array2[j] = NULL) {
  //do something
} else {
  //do something else
}
```

a statement like array = NULL is apparently an attempt to assign the variable NULL.  I don't want to do that, I just want to check if it exists.  What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Instead of `NULL`, use just `0` for non-pointer values and `nullptr` for pointer values.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this

```
if (array[i] != NULL && array2[j] == NULL) {
//do something
} else {
//do something else
}
```

one =  means assigning
two = means equaling

Answer (score 0):

Use == for equality comparison and != for negated equality comparison.